# Barchu or Kavana

Tags: tefilla, mistakes, maariv, priorities, kavana-concentration

If you are late to Maariv and miss barchu and you normally daven slowly should you...

- Daven faster, even if it means saying the words with little to no Kavana so that you can say Barchu at the end.

OR

- Daven as you normally would and miss Barchu entirely.

(Related, but not identical, to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3679/missing-barchu-by-maariv).)

Comment: no such thing as kavana

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on msh210's answer to [Missing Barchu at Maariv](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3679/missing-barchu-by-maariv) that there is no benefit in saying Borchu at the end of Maariv then it is better to Daven with Kavana.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you daven really slowly and still want tefillah b'tzibbur, you can wait until the tzibbur reaches the amidah and start that with them. Then, go back and say birkot shema, etc.

Comment: EliLansey, welcome to the site! I hope you enjoy it and stick around. A source for your contention that one can do such a thing would be most valuable.

Comment: Good point. I'll need to check out notes and sources when I get home from work.

Answer (score -1):

The Gemoro in Taanis 2a says, essentially, that prayer is the service of the heart. 
דתניא (דברים יא) "לאהבה את ה' אלהיכם ולעבדו בכל לבבכם" **איזו היא עבודה שהיא בלב הוי אומר זו תפלה**. It follows, I suggest, that where the heart (=kavana) is not involved it's not really (the ideal form of) prayer. Don't give up kavana for a barchu.

Also see the answers to this [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11328/can-i-omit-to-catch-up-in-maariv) about omitting the section ברוך השם לעולם אמן ואמן to daven amida with the tzibbur.

Comment: Maybe not hearing barchu is a less ideal form of prayer. You have no argument here (certainly not a sourced one).

Comment: FTR I didn't downvote.