# Arrived late for maariv. How to daven?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, tzibur-community, priorities, maariv

I arrived late for the last minyan for Maariv. Should I

A) Pray the amida with the community and lose the proximity of "geula" to "tefilla" 
but gain the "tefilla betzibbur" or

B) Pray in order, losing "tefilla betzibbur"?

Related to [Barchu or Kavana](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14253/barchu-or-kavana) and an unsourced comment there by Yahu.

Comment: What comment by Yahu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Shulchan Aruch*, *OC* 236:3:

> If someone discovered a group that had already read [the evening] "*Sh'ma*" and is about to say *amida* [of *maariv*], then he should say *amida* with them and then say "*Sh'ma*" with its blessings.

See more at "[What to do after sh'mone esre before Sh'ma](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26605)".